# OCaml compiler check for vector lengths

Tags: ocaml

I was wondering if it is possible to have compile-time check in OCaml to make sure arrays are the correct length. For my problem, I want to verify that two GPU 1-dim vectors are of the same length before doing piecewise vector subtraction.

```
let init_value = 1
let length = 10_000_000
let x = GpuVector.create length init_value and y = GpuVector.create 9 init_value in
let z = GpuVector.sub v1 v2
```

In this example I would like it to throw a compile error as x and y are not the same length. As I am a OCaml noob I would like to know how I can achieve this? I am guessing that I will have to use functors or camlp4 (which I have never used before)

Comment: OCaml itself has no dependent types, which can be used to check array length mismatch statically. One thing you can do is to use phantom types which carries a phantom encoding the array length. These encodings could be auto-generated from integer constants using CamlP4... But this is not dependent type and likely not enough for your purpose.

Comment: @camlspotter I just found your comment. Have a similar problem. Could you provide some hints/pointers on encoding natural numbers as types?

Comment: @krokodil,  now you can try slap, just as Pierre pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot define a type family in OCaml for `arrays of length n` where `n` can have arbitrary length.  It is however possible to use other mechanisms to ensure that you only `GpuVector.sub` arrays of compatible lengths.

The easiest mechanism to implement is defining a special module for `GpuVector` of length 9, and you can generalise the  9 by using functors.  Here is an example implementation of a module `GpuVectorFixedLength`:

```
module GpuVectorFixedLength =
struct
module type P =
sig
  val length : int
end

module type S =
sig
  type t
  val length : int
  val create : int -> t
  val sub : t -> t -> t
end

module Make(Parameter:P): S =
struct
  type t = GpuVector.t
  let length = Parameter.length
  let create x = GpuVector.create length x
  let sub = GpuVector.sub
end
end
```

You can use this by saying for instance

```
module GpuVectorHuge = GpuVectorFixedLength.Make(struct let length = 10_000_000 end)
module GpuVectorTiny = GpuVectorFixedLength.Make(struct let length = 9 end)
let x = GpuVectorHuge.create 1
let y = GpuVectorTiny.create 1
```

The definition of `z` is then rejected by the compiler:

```
let z = GpuVector.sub x y
                        ^
Error: This expression has type GpuVectorHuge.t
       but an expression was expected of type int array
```

We therefore successfully reflected in the type system the property for two arrays of having the same length. You can take advantage of module inclusion to quickly implement a complete `GpuVectorFixedLength.Make` functor.

Answer (score 2):

The [slap](https://github.com/akabe/slap) library implements such kind of size static checks (for linear algebra).
The overall approach is described [this abstract](https://ocaml.org/meetings/ocaml/2014/ocaml2014_19.pdf)

Comment: the link to the abstract seems defunct (404); do you know by chance where one can find it now?

Comment: This is not exactly the original abstract, but this is I think more complete
http://eptcs.web.cse.unsw.edu.au/paper.cgi?ML2014.1.pdf