# Extract nth element of a tuple

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

For a list, you can do pattern matching and iterate until the nth element, but for a tuple, how would you grab the nth element?

Comment: As the answers below allude to, you're using tuples incorrectly. This could be an artifact of how Python/other languages describes and uses them --in Python as an "immutable list". You never want to iterate over a tuple (instead, use an array or list), and if your tuple is large enough, it's best to use a record to name the fields.

Comment: It's fine to access the Nth element *as long as N is a compile time constant*. For example Rust allows `some_tuple.1` which is basically a more readable version of `snd some_tuple`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### **TL;DR;** Stop trying to access directly the *n*-th element of a *t*-uple and use a record or an array as they allow random access.

You can grab the *n*-th element by *unpacking* the *t*-uple with value deconstruction, either by a `let` construct, a `match` construct or a function definition:

```
let ivuple = (5, 2, 1, 1)

let squared_sum_let =
  let (a,b,c,d) = ivuple in
  a*a + b*b + c*c + d*d

let squared_sum_match =
  match ivuple with (a,b,c,d) -> a*a + b*b + c*c + d*d

let squared_sum_fun (a,b,c,d) =
  a*a + b*b + c*c + d*d
```

The `match`-construct has here no virtue over the `let`-construct, it is just included for the sake of completeness.

### Do not use *t*-uples, Don¹

There are only a few cases where using *t*-uples to represent a type is the right thing to do.  Most of the times, we pick a *t*-uple because we are too lazy to define a type and we should interpret the problem of accessing the *n*-th field of a *t*-uple or iterating over the fields of a *t*-uple as a serious signal that *it is time to switch to a proper type*.

There are two natural replacements to *t*-uples: *records* and *arrays.*

### When to use records

We can see a record as a *t*-uple whose entries are labelled; as such, they are definitely the most natural replacement to *t*-uples if we want to access them directly.

```
type ivuple = {
  a: int;
  b: int;
  c: int;
  d: int;
}
```

We then access directly the field `a` of a value `x` of type `ivuple` by writing `x.a`. Note that records are easily copied with modifications, as in `let y = { x with d = 0 }`. There is no natural way to iterate over the fields of a record, mostly because a record do not need to be homogeneous.

### When to use arrays

A large² homogeneous collection of values is adequately represented by an array, which allows direct access, iterating and folding. A possible inconvenience is that the size of an array is not part of its type, but for arrays of fixed size, this is easily circumvented by introducing a private type — or even an abstract type. I described an example of this technique in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25905600/2654678) to the question “OCaml compiler check for vector lengths”.

### Note on float boxing

When using floats in *t*-uples, in records *containing only floats* and in arrays, these are unboxed. We should therefore not notice any performance modification when changing from one type to the other in our numeric computations.

---

¹ See *the TeXbook*.
² Large starts near 4.

Answer (score 13):

Since the length of OCaml tuples is part of the type and hence known (and fixed) at compile time, you get the n-th item by straightforward pattern matching on the tuple. For the same reason, the problem of extracting the n-th element of an "arbitrary-length tuple" *cannot* occur in practice - such a "tuple" cannot be expressed in OCaml's type system.

You might still not want to write out a pattern every time you need to project a tuple, and nothing prevents you from generating the functions `get_1_1`...`get_i_j`... that extract the `i`-th element from a `j`-tuple for any possible combination of `i` and `j` occuring in your code, e.g.

```
let get_1_1 (a) = a
let get_1_2 (a,_) = a
let get_2_2 (_,a) = a
let get_1_3 (a,_,_) = a
let get_2_3 (_,a,_) = a
...
```

Not necessarily pretty, but possible.

**Note**: Previously I had claimed that OCaml tuples can have at most length 255 and you can simply generate all possible tuple projections once and for all. As @Virgile pointed out in the comments, this is incorrect - tuples can be huge. This means that it is impractical to generate *all* possible tuple projection functions upfront, hence the restriction "*occurring in your code*" above.

Comment: Tuples have a length limit, but it is much higher than 255 (the bound is the maximal size of an OCaml block, typically 2^22 or 2^54, see e.g. https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/memory-representation-of-values.html). 255 (and in fact something like 250 because some tags are reserved) is the maximal number of non-constant constructors that you can have in a sum type.

Comment: Batteries has modules for tuples up to 5. Past that, it's best to use records as things can easily become confusing.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to write such a function in full generality in OCaml. One way to see this is to think about what type the function would have. There are two problems. First, each size of tuple is a different type. So you can't write a function that accesses elements of tuples of different sizes. The second problem is that different elements of a tuple can have different types. Lists don't have either of these problems, which is why you can have `List.nth`.

If you're willing to work with a fixed size tuple whose elements are all the same type, you can write a function as shown by @user2361830.

**Update**

If you really have collections of values of the same type that you want to access by index, you should probably be using an array.

Answer (score 0):

here is a function wich return you the string of the ocaml function you need to do that ;) very helpful I use it frequently.

```
let tup len n = 
if n>=0 && n<len then
    let rec rep str nn = match nn<1 with 
        |true ->""
        |_->str ^ (rep str (nn-1))in
    let txt1 ="let t"^(string_of_int len)^"_"^(string_of_int n)^" tup = match tup with |" ^ (rep "_," n) ^ "a" and
    txt2 =","^(rep "_," (len-n-2)) and
    txt3 ="->a" in
    if n = len-1 then
        print_string (txt1^txt3)
    else
        print_string (txt1^txt2^"_"^txt3)
else raise (Failure "Error") ;;
```

For example:

```
tup 8  6;;
```

return:

```
let t8_6 tup = match tup with |_,_,_,_,_,_,a,_->a
```

and of course:

```
val t8_6 : 'a * 'b * 'c * 'd * 'e * 'f * 'g * 'h -> 'g = <fun>
```